# Efficiency with php code header

Tags: php, wordpress

This code isn't optimal and I am struggling to find a better way of doing it.

Basically, you click a button which sends an ajax request to this file listed below which gets a random post from a WordPress database. Quite often these are repeated and gives the impression that it is not working, to combat this I checked if current id = old id, if they are the same get a new post, however I have not found a way to run another wpquery inside of another query.

```
<?php
    require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
?>
    <span id="postss"><?php
        query_posts(array(
            'cat' => 39,
            'order' => 'ASC', // ASC
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'showposts' => 1,
            ));
        $wp_query->is_archive = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['oldId']))
        {
            $_SESSION['oldId'] = get_the_id();
        }else{
            $curId = get_the_id();
            if($_SESSION['oldId'] == $curId)
            {
                header("Location: http://website.com/testimonialPull.php");     
            }else{


    the_content();
        }
        $_SESSION['oldId'] = get_the_id();
    }

    endwhile; endif;

?>
```

So sending the header request takes about 1 seconds for a new post to show, whereas normally its about 2/10ths of a second. Is there a more efficient and faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your `query_posts()` call like so:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => 39,
    'order' => 'ASC', // ASC
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'showposts' => 1,
);
if ( isset( $_SESSION['oldId'] ) {
    $args['post__not_in'] = array( $_SESSION['oldId'] );
}
query_posts( $args );
```

The `post__not_in` argument specifies an array of ID's which will be excluded from the query.

If you want to read more about the `WP_Query` class and the arguments it accepts(those match with the ones the `query_posts()` accepts) - see the codex page - [Class Reference/WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

PP: I don't see why you don't just hook a function on the `init` action hook and make the query to `http://website.com/?pullTestimonial=1`(I'm not sure if this will slow done the process, but that's usually how I achieve this)

Here is an example code:

```
function fetch_testimonial() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['pullTestimonial'] ) ) {
        // Your code that will be executed goes here
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'fetch_testimonial', 10);
```

What you win from this is that you don't need to have a file somewhere in your root directory or your link won't be like http://website.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/testimonialPull.php